# How to display websites containing searched keyword on Google Spreadsheet using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently the **Google Script** code I have creates a button that prompts the user for a keyword to search for. It then is *supposed to* return the results on a spreadsheet by retrieving their URL/Name/Title and displaying them in their respective columns on Google Sheets. I want to be able to have the search, search through a particular site that hosts links to subpages of the site and return the sites that contain the searched term anywhere on that site and paste the results onto a spreadsheet.
**EDIT**
The problem I get when running the code is that after searching the keyword, the spreadsheet returns a dialog box indicating that the "resource you requested could not be located" but the website I am searching through does in fact have the keyword on multiple pages.
This is the code I need help with:

```
function websearch() {
  // Prompt the user for a search term
  var websearchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Enter the keyword to search for:");

  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var wss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wsheet = wss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
  var theaders = [["Name", "Title", "Web Address"]];
  wsheet.clear();
  wsheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(theaders);

  // Search the webpages associated with the given URL 
  var site = SitesApp.getSite("https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/hb-ua/");
  //var matches = site.search(websearchTerm);
  var matches = site.search("fullText contains '"+websearchTerm.replace("'","\'")+"'");

  var woutput = [];
  // Loop through the results and get the file name, file title, and URL
  while (site.hasNext()) {
    var wfile = site.next();
    var wname = wfile.getName();
    var wtitle = wfile.getTitle();
    var wurl = wfile.getUrl();
    // push the file details to our output array (essentially pushing a row of data)
    woutput.push([wname, wtitle, wurl]);
  }
  // write data to the sheet
  wsheet.getRange(2, 1, woutput.length, 3).setValues(woutput);

}
```

Then this code I know for sure works, it does what I am asking help for, but searches through google drive instead of google sites/specific parent websites:

```
function search(Phrase, FolderID) {
  // Prompt the user for a search term
  var searchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Enter the string to search for:");

  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
  var headers = [["File Name", "File Type", "URL"]];
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);

  // Search the files in the user's Google Drive for the search term based on if the word is included in thefile or name
  // Search Reference Guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("fullText contains '"+searchTerm.replace("'","\'")+"'");
  //var SearchString = 'fullText contains "' + Phrase + '" and "' + FolderID + '" in parents';
  //var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(SearchString);
  // create an array to store our data to be written to the sheet 
  var output = [];
  // Loop through the results and get the file name, file type, and URL
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    var name = file.getName();
    var type = file.getMimeType();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    // push the file details to our output array (essentially pushing a row of data)
    output.push([name, type, url]);
  }
  // write data to the sheet
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, 3).setValues(output);
}
```

This is the search dialog prompt code:

```
 function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];
  var websearchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "websearch"}];
  ss.addMenu("Search Google Drive", searchMenuEntries);
  ss.addMenu("Search UMich", websearchMenuEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't describe what is wrong, or what error is shown.

But your analogy script transformed from Drive's script is looking good except one thing:

- method `DriveApp.searchFiles()` [returns FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams), but
- method `Site.search()` [return just Array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#searchquery) of Pages.

Try to use `for()`, `foreach()` or `.forEach()` instead of `.next()` to iteration.

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited my post to better clarify the problem i have

Comment: How would I best use a forEach() to go through the pages?

Comment: I am not usig Sites too few, but basen on error message can be problem at `SitesApp.getSite()`. You as argument using URl of site, but [documentation of method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#getsitename) say it expect name. Try to use [`SitesApp.getSiteByUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#getsitebyurlurl) instead.